# Apache Flume sourcing data from python script

Tags: python, pyspark, streaming, flume

I am running a python script to collect data from news providers and sourcing this script in flume.conf file.

## My flume.conf file:

```
newsAgent.sources = r1
newsAgent.sinks = spark
newsAgent.channels = MemChannel

# Describe/configure the source
newsAgent.sources.r1.type = exec
newsAgent.sources.r1.command = python path_to/data_collector.py

# Describe the sink
newsAgent.sinks.spark.type = avro
newsAgent.sinks.spark.channel = memoryChannel
newsAgent.sinks.spark.hostname = localhost
newsAgent.sinks.spark.port = 4040

# Use a channel which buffers events in memory
newsAgent.channels.MemChannel.type = memory
newsAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity = 10000
newsAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity = 100

# Bind the source and sink to the channel
newsAgent.sources.r1.channels = MemChannel
newsAgent.sinks.spark.channel = MemChannel
```

python script in insolation running fine and i can see the json data getting printed. But when i am executing it via flume and sinking the data to spark getting below warning messages.

## WARNING MESSAGES

```
18/08/04 07:36:20 WARN HttpParser: Illegal character 0x0 in state=START 
for buffer HeapByteBuffer@5ae61d8b[p=1,l=8192,c=8192,r=8191]= . {\x00<<<\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x000\x86\xAa\xDa\xE2\xC4T...ing town", "sum>>>}
18/08/04 07:36:20 WARN HttpParser: bad HTTP parsed: 400 Illegal character 0x0 for HttpChannelOverHttp@46691f53{r=0,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=null}
```

## data_collector.py

```
def process():
    for k, v in news_source.items():
        feeds = feedparser.parse(v)
        for e in feeds.entries:
            doc = json.dumps(
                {"news_provider": k, "title": e.title.strip(), "summary": BeautifulSoup(e.summary, 'lxml').text.strip(),
                 "id": e.id.strip(), "published": e.published if e.has_key('published') else None})
            print("%s"%doc)
```

## Streaming_script

```
def func():
    sc = SparkContext(master="local[*]", appName="App")
    ssc  = StreamingContext(sc, 300)
    flume_strm = FlumeUtils.createStream(ssc, "localhost", 9999)

    lines = flume_strm.map(lambda v: json.loads(v[1]))
    lines.pprint()
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

## Commands used

```
bin/flume-ng agent --conf conf --conf-file libexec/conf/test.conf --name Agent -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console

spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-flume_2.11:2.2.0  path_to/streaming_script.py
```

I am not able to get rid of those warning messages and i am expecting same json data to get printed in spark logs using pprint(), later on i can process those messages accordingly.

Am i missing any specific configuration while reading streamed content?
Do i need to specify any specific encoders?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I must have watched the same tutorial as you. I tried many different options. Most did not succeed. However I found a work-around: use an exec source in your flume.conf and call the script exactly as you are doing. However in your python script, write the data to a file. Then "cat" the file before your script (data_collector.py) stops executing.

I think this is because the exec source needs to "stream" data, and simply printing your output will not work.

My setup is very similar to yours:

stream.py (with logic removed for ease of understanding):

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.flume import FlumeUtils

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sc = SparkContext(appName="test");
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 30)
    stream = FlumeUtils.createStream(ssc, "127.0.0.1", 55555)
    stream.pprint()
```

And here is my data_collector.py (note the last line with the "cat" command):

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import requests
import random


class RandResp():
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = "https://swapi.co/api/people/"
        self.rand = str(random.randint(0, 17))
        self.r = requests.get(self.url + self.rand)

    def get_r(self):
        return(self.r.text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import os
    with open("exec.txt", "w") as file_in:
        file_in.write(RandResp().get_r())
    os.system("cat exec.txt")
```

here is my flume.conf:

```
# list sources, sinks and channels in the agent
agent.sources = tail-file
agent.channels = c1
agent.sinks=avro-sink

# define the flow
agent.sources.tail-file.channels = c1
agent.sinks.avro-sink.channel = c1
agent.channels.c1.type = memory
agent.channels.c1.capacity = 1000

# define source and sink
agent.sources.tail-file.type = exec
agent.sources.tail-file.command =  python /home/james/Desktop/testing/data_collector.py
agent.sources.tail-file.channels = c1
agent.sinks.avro-sink.type = avro
agent.sinks.avro-sink.hostname = 127.0.0.1
agent.sinks.avro-sink.port = 55555
```

So basically in my data_collector.py, I just do whatever logic needs to be done, write it to a file called exec.txt, and then immediately "cat" the file. It works... Good Luck